# Time Limit exceeded on LeetCode

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the Leetcode's Two Sum problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) and my code runs well on small lists,

but the website outputs me 'time limit exceeded' when trying this list and target (https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/845707290/testcase/) (19999), although my coding environment outputs [9998, 9999] (after some time though)

```
x = 0
y = 1
while x < len(nums):
    if x == y:
        y += 1
    if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
        L = [x, y]
        print(L)
        break
    if y == len(nums) - 1:
        x += 1
        y = 0
    if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
        L = [x, y]
        print(L)
        break
    #if x == len(nums) - 1:
    #    y += 1
    #    x = 0
    elif (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
        L = [x, y]
        print(L)
        break
    y += 1
```

(My code in Leetcode contains return instead of print as it's a part of function)
Thanks.

Here is the code on LeetCode

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        x = 0
        y = 1
        while x < len(nums):
            if x == y:
                y += 1
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                L = [x, y]
                return L
                break
            if y == len(nums) - 1:
                x += 1
                y = 0
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                L = [x, y]
                return L
                break    
            #if x == len(nums) - 1:
            #    y += 1
            #    x = 0
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                L = [x, y]
                return L
                break
            y += 1
```

UPDATE 1

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        x = 0
        y = 1
        while x < len(nums):
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                L = [x, y]
                return L
            if y == len(nums) - 1:
                x += 1
                y = x + 1
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                L = [x, y]
                return L
            y += 1
```

Comment: The online IDE simply won't give you the resources to complete more lengthy tasks (therefore time limit exceeded)

Comment: Can't you use range to directly define the list in your function?

Comment: Also, I believe break isn't necessary when you return.

Comment: When Leetcode tells you that your code is taking too long to run that generally means that although your code may (eventually) output the correct results your algorithm is flawed

Comment: You're checking `nums[x] + nums[y]) == target` three times for every pair of elements where it is false (which is almost always). You're also checking every (x, y) pairing except one on all iterations, which is approximately twice the work as when you ignore the ones you've already tried. (`y` should start at `x+1`, not at 0.)

Comment: I've updated my code to the version above, and tested it with the IDE and was finished in about 52s (with print and breaks instead of return) and the same issue persists in Leetcode

Comment: I don't know whether I should change the whole logic, but my problem is I don't have the full Python knowledge to understand most of the programs below as I'm still learning

Comment: But if there is no solution except changing the whole logic, I can go for it

Comment: @MohamedHassan, I would suggest my for-loop then, it's the most intuitive solution suggested.

Comment: @MohamedHassan, any progress updates?

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary to create a performant lookup.

```
nums = [1,5,2,7,21]
target = 23

lookup = { k:v for (v,k) in enumerate(nums) }

for a in nums:
    b = target - a
    if lookup.get(b, None):
        print([lookup[a], lookup[b]])
        break
```

Output:

```
[2, 4]
```

Moving `lookup.get()` to the assignment of `b` will improve performance further:

```
def sum_of_two(nums, target):
    lookup = { value:index for (index, value) in enumerate(nums) }
    for a in nums:
        b = lookup.get(target - a, None)
        if b is not None:
            return([lookup[a], b])
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @Nineteendo in the comments, the straight up dictionary lookup can't handle duplicates in the list. However if the dictionary is populated while iterating through the list of numbers then this case is handled.

```
def sum_of_two_edit(nums, target):
    lookup = {}
    for i, a in enumerate(nums):
        b = target - a
        j = lookup.get(b, None)
        if j is not None:
            return [j, i]
        lookup[a] = i
```

Sample input:

```
nums = [1,2,3,3,6]
target = 6

sum_of_two_edit(nums, target)
```

Result:

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: What do you think of my analysis below?

Comment: Sadly, no duplicates are allowed, like [3,3] with target 6. Which makes a dictionary not work.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've updated my answer to include a function for handling that scenario.

Comment: Should I remove the non- working suggestions?

Comment: That's up to you, the edited solution will be a fraction of a second faster because only in the worst case scenario does it need to populate the entire lookup dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code isn't quite linearly scaling yet, maybe search further. (Definitely use datetime to track the time).
Attempt 1 of Mohamed Hassan:

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
nums = list(range(1,10_000 + 1))
target = 19_999
x = 0
y = 1
while x < len(nums):
    if x == y:
        y += 1
    if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
        print([x, y])
        break
    if y == len(nums) - 1:
        x += 1
        y = 0
    if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
        print([x, y])
        break
    if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
        print([x, y])
        break
    y += 1
print("Finished in:", datetime.now() - start)
```

Result:

```
[9998, 9999]
Finished in: 0:04:43.237951
```

Attempt 2 of Mohamed Hassan, using a class:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        x = 0
        y = 1
        while x < len(nums):
            if x == y:
                y += 1
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                return [x, y]
            if y == len(nums) - 1:
                x += 1
                y = 0
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                return [x, y]    
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target: 
                return [x, y]
            y += 1

start = datetime.now()
nums = list(range(1, 10_000 + 1))
target = 19_999
print(Solution().twoSum(nums, target))
print("Finished in:", datetime.now() - start)
```

Result:

```
[9998, 9999]
Finished in: 0:03:47.205079
```

attempt 3 of Mohamed Hassan, with some optimisations:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        x = 0
        y = 1
        while x < len(nums):
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                return [x, y]
            if y == len(nums) - 1:
                x += 1
                y = x + 1
            if (nums[x] + nums[y]) == target:
                return [x, y]
            y += 1

start = datetime.now()
nums = list(range(1, 10_000 + 1))
target = 19_999
print(Solution().twoSum(nums, target))
print("Finished in:", datetime.now() - start)
```

Result:

```
[9998, 9999]
Finished in: 0:01:25.186796
```

Attempt 1 of me, Nineteendo, using a for loop instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
nums = list(range(1,10_000 + 1))
target = 19_999
for i, x in enumerate(nums):
    for j, y in enumerate(nums[i + 1:]):
        if x + y == target:
            break
    if x + y == target:
        print([i, i + 1 + j])
        break
print("Finished in:", datetime.now() - start)
```

Result:

```
[9998, 9999]
Finished in: 0:00:28.605655
```

Attempt 2 of me, Nineteendo, using a function too to avoid the second break, it's also a lot faster:

```
from datetime import datetime
def find_sum(nums, target):
    for i, x in enumerate(nums):
        for j, y in enumerate(nums[i + 1:]):
            if x + y == target:
                return [i, i + 1 + j]

start = datetime.now()
nums = list(range(1, 10_000 + 1))
target = 19_999
print(find_sum(nums, target))
print("Finished in:", datetime.now() - start)
```

Result:

```
[9998, 9999]
Finished in: 0:00:18.117496
```

Attempt 3 of Dan Nagle, using a math solution, and a function:

```
from datetime import datetime
def sum_of_two_edit(nums, target):
    lookup = {}
    for i, a in enumerate(nums):
        b = target - a
        j = lookup.get(b, None)
        if j is not None:
            return [j, i]
        lookup[a] = i

start = datetime.now()
nums = list(range(1, 10_000 + 1))
target = 19_999
print(sum_of_two_edit(nums, target))
print("Finished in:", datetime.now() - start)
```

Result:

```
[9998, 9999]
Finished in: 0:00:00.010349
```

Attempt 1 of Cobra, also using a for loop:

```
from datetime import datetime
def twoSum(nums, target):
        d = {}
        for i, n in enumerate(nums):
            if (j := d.get(target - n)) is not None:
                return [i, j]
            d[n] = i
start = datetime.now()
nums = list(range(1, 10_000 + 1))
target = 19_999
print(twoSum(nums, target))
print("Finished in:", datetime.now() - start)
```

Result:

```
[9999, 9998]
Finished in: 0:00:00.009762
```

Comment: The dictionary approach is an excellent one. However, for the sake of completeness it's worth pointing out that this does not satisfy the Leetcode constraint in that no two elements can be duplicated. For example, if the list is [3,3] and the target is 6, Leetcode requires a response of either [0,1] or [1,0] whereas this code returns [1,1]

Comment: I don't think you could do much about that. I believe the other methods could be adapted to that constraint, though.

Comment: @Cobra, I believe the for loops are the best solution, now that I fixed their problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a reasonably efficient implementation then you could try this:

```
    def twoSum(nums, target):
        d = {}
        for i, n in enumerate(nums):
            if (b := target - n) in d:
                return [i, d[b]]
            d[n] = i
```

For the list containing inclusive values 1 -> 10000 and a target of 19999, this returns [9999, 9998] in 0.0012s

Comment: what must I import for the List?

Comment: You'll need to import *typing* or just remove the hints. I only left them there because that's what Leetocde requires. I'll simplify it

Comment: Ok, now I included your answer too.

Answer (score -1):

I thought about the O(n²) problematic and additonally I wanted to have it elegant :D.

Pythons tim-sort (`sorted()`, `[].sort()`) is O(n*log(n)) which is indeed better :).

So what I did:

1. Sort the input array (O(n * log(n))
2. iterate with two indizes through the array: one on the right and one on the left O(2*n) = O(n)
3. When the result is too large: move right one to the left
4. when the result is too low: move left one to the right
5. When the result == target: find the indizes O(2*n) again
6. Tada.

In code:

```py
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    sorted_list = list(sorted(nums))  # the most expensive part
    left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1  # start at the ends
    result = -1  # any value which is not "possible" suffices
    while result != target:
        if result < target:
            left += 1
        elif result > targe:t
            right -= 1
        value_left, value_right = sorted_list[left], sorted_list[right]
        result = value_left + value_right

    return [nums.index(value_left), nums.index(value_right)]
```

Comment: If the *nums* list is [3,2,4] and the *target* is 6 this code (after fixing the syntax error) returns [0,0] whereas it should be [1,2] or [2,1]